# how to take unique values in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, ADRESS
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.CustomerID=B.CustomerID
WHERE 
Points > 15
```

So after it gives me the result with customerIDs and adresses, but incase customer may have 2 IDs, for example he or she has twice registered, however address is the same.

How can i take only unique values by adress, so i would like that adress were unique, if there are two different IDs but they have the same adress the sql has to leave only 1 value.

Please help!

Comment: Could you Post Some Example...to make it much clearer?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you do have an address with multiple ID's - which of the ID's do you want to see??

Comment: It does not matter. All i need is to have unique address and customerid infront of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ADRESS, MAX(A.CustomerID) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.CustomerID=B.CustomerID WHERE Points > 15
GROUP BY ADRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly I would suggest to use a `GROUP BY address`.
By grouping multiple customers by the same address you will run into problems if there are two different customers which are living at the same address. To prevent this you could also add the name of the customer to the group by. It should be fairly unlikely that two people with the same name live at the same address but it still could happen...

Comment: Hei, but i need CustomerID not his name. CustomerID generated by the programm, so they are unique, however address can be the same. If i will group by adress sql does not allow it and ask to group by customerid as well.

Comment: You will have to use an aggregation function on the customerId row like `MAX()`